# Adjust font in list of theorems in memoir

Tags: fonts, memoir, thmtools

I am using `memoir` with the `\listoftheorems` of the `thmtools` package. I would like to use the sffamily font for typesetting the list of theorems.

As `\listoftheorems` uses `\listoffigures` internally, I tried setting `\renewcommand{\cftfigurefont}{\normalsize\sffamily}` but that changed only the list of figures (see MWE below). Checking the `thm-listof.sty`, I still did not find where to adjust this.

How can I adjust the font used for typesetting the list of theorems?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter] 

\begin{document}


    \renewcommand{\cftfigurefont}{\normalsize\sffamily}

    \listoffigures

    \listoftheorems

    \begin{theorem}
        My first theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}
        My second theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{figure}
        My favorite figure.
        \caption{My favorite figure's caption.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: My aim (of this question) is to typeset the list of theorems, not the theorems themselves.

Comment: Have you tried adding \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} after \usepackage{thmtools}?

Comment: @Tina I just tried it. But as afar as I can see, this changes all text to sf. But I would like to keep the rest as is and just change the font of the entries in the list of theorems.

Comment: okay, so you only want the list of theorems \listoftheorems to be in a different font, not the actual theorems in the body of your document?

Comment: yes. I added a comment to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\listoftheorems` command sets up every `\contentsline` to do the standard `book` class actions.

With the patch proposed below, every entry is treated as if it were a figure caption.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter] 

\renewcommand{\cftfigurefont}{\normalsize\sffamily} % should be in the preamble
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\listoftheorems}
 {\let\thref@starttoc\@starttoc}
 {%
  \@for\thmt@envname:=\thmt@allenvs\do{%
    \@xa\let\csname l@\thmt@envname\endcsname\l@figure
  }%
  \let\cftfigurenumwidth\thmt@listnumwidth
  \let\thref@starttoc\@starttoc
 }{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\listoftheorems

\begin{theorem}
My first theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
My second theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{figure}[htp]
My favorite figure.
\caption{My favorite figure's caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the choice to change the font for the list of theorems and list of figures and if you like the theorems themselves. Hope it is useful and what you intended.[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

% here you can style your theorem entries, instead of using above line
\declaretheoremstyle[
%change to \normalfont\sffamily, if you wanted sans-serif for theorem entries
spaceabove=3pt, spacebelow=3pt, headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={(}{)}, bodyfont=\normalfont]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=theorem, name=Theroem, numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}

%this sets up the font for list of theorems
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{\sffamily{List of my Theorems}} %needed for title
\newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont}{\par} %needed for list entries

%this sets up the font for list of figures
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{\sffamily{List of my figures}} %needed for title
\renewcommand{\cftfigurefont}{\sffamily} %needed for list entires

\begin{document}

    \listoffigures

    \begin{myfont}
        \listoftheorems
    \end{myfont}

    \vspace{2cm} %some space

    \begin{theorem}
        My first theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}
        My second theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \vspace{1cm} %some space

    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        My favorite figure.
        \caption{My favorite figure's caption.}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks. But is there a way to encapsulate that so that I can just call `\listoftheorems` without having to add the specific environment around. My idea would be something like `\let\Listoftheorems\listoftheorems` and then `\renewcommand{\listoftheorems}{\begin{myfont}\Listoftheorems\end{myfont}}`. But then I can't pass any of the paramters to `\listoftheorems` and I do need that.